# Convert object to array of key–value objects like `{ name: "Apple", value: "0.6" }`

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like this:

```js
const total = {
    "Apple": 0.6,
    "Banana": 0.6,
    "Orange": 1,
    "Grapes": 0.4,
    "Pineapple": 0.4
  };
```

Now I want to convert it into an array of key–value objects where each object has the same set of two properties, `"name"` and `"value"`, which hold the key and value, respectively, of each property of the original object:

```js
[
  { "name": "Apple", "value": 0.6 },
  { "name": "Banana", "value": 0.6 },
  { "name": "Orange", "value": 1 },
  { "name": "Grapes", "value": 0.4 },
  { "name": "Pineapple", "value": 0.4 }
]
```

Comment: If you’re looking for the inverse of this: [How do I convert array of Objects into one Object in JavaScript?](/q/19874555/4642212).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on the object keys and create your objects with desired shape.

```js
const total = { 
    'Apple': 0.6,
    'Banana': 0.6,
    'Orange': 1,
    'Grapes': 0.4,
    'Pineapple': 0.4 
};
              
const array = Object.keys(total)
                    .map(key => ({ name: key, value: total[key] }))
                    .sort((f, s) => f.value - s.value);

console.log(array);
```

If you use *ES7* or higher you can replace [**Object#keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [**Object#entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Use also [**object destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the parameter list to get `name` and `value` separately.

```js
const total = { 
    'Apple': 0.6,
    'Banana': 0.6,
    'Orange': 1,
    'Grapes': 0.4,
    'Pineapple': 0.4 
};
              
const array = Object.entries(total)
                    .map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }))
                    .sort((f, s) => f.value - s.value);;

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Seriously Awsome and really fast. Now If I want the result on Decreasing value order format then how I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to add `sort` function into the chain.

Answer (score 7):

```
 const result = Object.entries(total).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));
```

Comment: A little explanation goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) can also be used to "Insert object on array in key value format":

```js
var total = { 'Apple': 0.6, 'Banana': 0.6, 'Orange': 1, 'Grapes': 0.4, 'Pineapple': 0.4 };

var objArr = Object.entries(total)
                   .reduce((accumulator, [name, value]) => {
                      return accumulator.concat({name: name, value: value});  // creates an array of objects
                     }, [])
                   .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);  // sorting in descending order

console.log(objArr);
```

For more info read [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).