# Split values from array with objects to a different object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically I have this data:

```
const arrayWithDates = [{2023-06-02: 2, 2023-06-21: 6},{
{2023-06-29: 2, 2023-06-23: 1}]
```

But I would like to transform the previous array to this:

```
Const arrayTransformed = [[{count:'2', date:'2023-06-02'}, {count:'6', date:'2023-06-21'}],[{count:'2', date:'2023-06-29'},{count:'1', date:'023-06-23'}]]
```

Comment: Asking someone to write code for you is not not a question. What have you attempted? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your first array is invalid (an extra curly bracket was included on the first line `{`, and the keys are not strings, numbers, or Symbols). Besides that, this seems awfully similar to [Convert object to array of key–value objects like `{ name: "Apple", value: "0.6" }`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47863275/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map each record to an an array by converting the object to entries.

You will need to map each record's key to a `date` field and the associated value to a `count` field.

```js
const arrayWithDates = [
  { '2023-06-02': 2, '2023-06-21': 6 },
  { '2023-06-29': 2, '2023-06-23': 1 }
]

const arrayTransformed = arrayWithDates.map(record =>
  Object.entries(record).map(([date, count]) =>
    ({ count: `${count}`, date })));

console.log(arrayTransformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Output

```json
[
  [
    { "count": "2", "date": "2023-06-02" },
    { "count": "6", "date": "2023-06-21" }
  ],
  [
    { "count": "2", "date": "2023-06-29" },
    { "count": "1", "date": "2023-06-23" }
  ]
]
```

If you want to flatten the data, call `flat()`.

```js
const arrayWithDates = [
  { '2023-06-02': 2, '2023-06-21': 6 },
  { '2023-06-29': 2, '2023-06-23': 1 }
]

const arrayTransformed = arrayWithDates.map(record =>
  Object.entries(record).map(([date, count]) =>
    ({ count: `${count}`, date }))).flat();

console.log(arrayTransformed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Output

```json
[
  { "count": "2", "date": "2023-06-02" },
  { "count": "6", "date": "2023-06-21" }
  { "count": "2", "date": "2023-06-29" },
  { "count": "1", "date": "2023-06-23" }
]
```

Comment: I think it would reasonable to say this is almost exact same answer as mine, and your additions could have been added as a comment.

Comment: @Lavie Funny thing to comment about when both answers are pretty much the same as answers on the duplicate I pointed to 9 minutes before you answered...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates in `arrayWithDates` are formatted as strings, this should work:

```
const arrayTransformed = arrayWithDates.map(obj => {
   return Object.entries(obj).map(([date, count]) => {
   return { date, count: count.toString() };
   });
 });
```